# How to make unit tests for Redstone with PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, unit-testing, dart

I'm trying to make unit tests for Redstone microframework with PostgreSQL extension. Test of simple Route without pgsql request works fine. But when Route contains pgsql requests test fails because resp.statusCode=500. When I call application function with pgsql request directly from test it returns error because app.request is null. Here is code sample:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------
// Redstone application
library rs_app;
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:redstone/server.dart' as app;
import 'package:redstone_mapper/plugin.dart';
import 'package:redstone_mapper_pg/manager.dart';

Future startServer() {
  var uri = "postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb";
  var dbManager = new PostgreSqlManager(uri, min: 1, max: 3);
  app.addPlugin(getMapperPlugin(dbManager));
  app.setupConsoleLog();
  return app.start(address: '127.0.0.1', port: 8100);
}

PostgreSql get pgsql => app.request.attributes.dbConn;

@app.Route("/simple")
simpleAnswer() => "Hello, world!";

@app.Route("/complex")
complexAnswer() => getMaxId();

Future getMaxId() {
  return pgsql.query("select max(id) as id from t_test", String)
  .then((id) {
    return new Future.value(id[0]['id']);
  });
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
// Unit tests
library rs_app_test;
import 'package:rs_app/rs_app.dart' as rs_app;
import 'package:redstone/server.dart' as app;
import 'package:redstone/mocks.dart';
import 'package:unittest/unittest.dart';

main() => makeTests();

void makeTests() {
  setUp(() => app.setUp([#rs_app]));
  tearDown(() => app.tearDown());
  test('simple - PASS', () {
    var req = new MockRequest('/simple');
    return app.dispatch(req).then((resp) {
      expect(resp.statusCode, equals(200));
      expect(resp.mockContent, equals("Hello, world!"));
    });
  });
  test('complex - FAIL', () {
    var req = new MockRequest('/complex');
    return app.dispatch(req).then((resp) {
      expect(resp.statusCode, equals(200));
      expect(resp.mockContent, equals("0297"));
    });
  });
  test('direct - ERROR', () {
    return rs_app.getMaxId().then((id) {
      expect(id, equals("0297"));
    });
  });
}
```

I understand that dbManager is not initialized correctly, but how I must initialize it?

---

After Günter suggestion I experimented and found some solution for tests:

```
void makeTests() async {
  //setUp(() => app.setUp([#rs_app])); not needed
  //tearDown(() => app.tearDown()); closes all (and db-connection!) after each test
  await rs_app.startServer();
  test('simple - PASS', () { ... });
  test('complex - PASS NOW', () { ... });
  test('direct - STILL ERROR', () { ... });
}
```

Direct test returns error "The null object does not have a getter 'attributes'" i.e. app.request in getMaxId() is null. I think the reason is that http-request does not exist in direct test - and app.request too. It is needed to change access to PostgreSQL connection in getMaxId().

---

Redstone gives access to DB-connection during http-request handling only. If we want to test some DB-functions without http-request context we must care about DB-connection in our tests:

```
//--------------------------------------------------------
// Redstone application
// needed imports
PostgreSqlManager dbManager;
Future startServer() {
  var uri = "postgres://127.0.0.1:5432/testdb";
  dbManager = new PostgreSqlManager(uri, min: 1, max: 3);
  app.addPlugin(getMapperPlugin(dbManager));
  app.setupConsoleLog();
  return app.start(address: '127.0.0.1', port: 8100);
}
// skip to getMaxId()
Future getMaxId([PostgreSql test_pgsql]) {
  var _pgsql = app.request == null ? test_pgsql : pgsql;
  return _pgsql.query("select max(id) as id from t_test", String)
  .then((id) {
    return new Future.value(id[0]['id']);
  });
}

//--------------------------------------------------------
// Unit tests
// skip to direct test
  test('direct - PASS NOW', () async {
    var pgsql = await rs_app.dbManager.getConnection();
    return rs_app.getMaxId(pgsql).then((id) {
      rs_app.dbManager.closeConnection(pgsql);
      expect(id, equals("0297"));
    });
  });
// skip other
```

I think I answered on my question :)

Comment: Where do you start `server()` from?

Comment: This line looks fishy: "pgsql.query("select max(id) as id from t_test", String)", why is the String class being passed in here?

Comment: Greg, redstone_mapper_pg uses `PostgreSql.query(String sql, Type type, [values])` and String as second argument is workable trick for simple requests.